# How to get the number of anonymous function input arguments

Tags: matlab, anonymous-function

How can I get the length of `y`?

```
>> s=10; r=28; b=8/3;
>> f = @(t,y) [-s*y(1)+s*y(2); -y(1)*y(3)+r*y(1)-y(2); y(1)*y(2)-b*y(3)];
```

In the above example the length is `3`. Also since the `t` is the only independent variable, the length of `y` can be found by the length of the function `f`, that is `4` here.

**EDIT**

I want to write a system of differential equations solver like `ode45()` function. Here is an example

```
[t y] = ode45(f,[0 1],[1 0 0]);
```

Comment: Dont understend. "number of anonymous function input arguments". the f has two input arguments, t and y. How did you get 3 or 4?

Comment: The `y` itself is an array of 3 arguments `y(1)`,`y(2)` and `y(3)`.

Comment: The use numel(y) or size(y).

Comment: What is the end goal?  If `f`'s definition depends on `y`'s length, you should create a separate function file as creating an inline function like this doesn't generally let you deal with those kinds of complexities.

Comment: `numel(y)`, `size(y)` and `length(y)` doesn't work (Matlab says "Undefined function or variable 'y'.").

Comment: Type `edit ode45` and `edit private/odearguments` in your command window. `ode45` does this by making assumptions based on the size of the initial condition vector and by actually evaluating the the integration function while determining the initial step size. If errors occur they are either caught or it's the user's problem. Note that while sometimes we think of arrays as functions with "arguments", it's much clearer to say that they have "elements." I'm unsure why you need to know this information from the integration function.

Answer (score 1):

I still dont fully understand. But from the little I do undestend, it seams you want to look inside the function f, and look for y(1), y(2) or y(3) to see how many elements the y has? If this is the case you can do it as follows:

```
f = @(t,y) [-s*y(1)+s*y(2); -y(1)*y(3)+r*y(1)-y(2); y(1)*y(2)-b*y(3)];           
matchStr = regexp(func2str(f),'y\(\d\)','match');
numel(unique(matchStr))
```

This gives: 3

Basically what it does it to make f into string, and then searches for `y(\d)` in this string.

And just in case you want to have the number of  anonymous function input arguments, than you can use:

```
nargin(f)
```

This gives: 2 (because you have t and y as inputs to f)

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is correct, but it doesn't seem pretty and doesn't work if the user uses `x` instead of `y`. I don't think Matlab uses this in its functions of differential equations like `ode45()`. There should be a better way.

Comment: So why not to check how ode45 is doing this? just edit ode45 and you hsould see the source code. Maybe this will provide some anwsers.

Comment: @user96402 just check for `(\d)` without the `y` if you are not sure if will be called `y`, or you could check first what is the name of the input parameter before you build the regex.